# Typo in site CSS disables visited link color in community bulletin

Tags: bug, design, hyperlinks, community-bulletin

While looking into the math.SE style sheet for [this bug report](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12902/visited-questions-are-practically-indistinguishable-in-search-results), I happened to notice a simple typo:

```
.module.community-bulletin avisited{
    color:#32455d !important
}
```

Obviously, that should read:

```
.module.community-bulletin a:visited{
    color:#32455d !important
}
```

As a result of this typo, visited links are indistiguishable from unvisited ones in the community bulletin on math.SE.  Adding back the missing colon into `a:visited` fixes the bug.

Ps. The same typo occurs also in the meta.math.SE style sheet.

Comment: It seems that this visited link styling has since been completely removed; the style is simply no longer there, with or without the typo.